# New magento website + old database

Tags: mysql, products, sql

I've set up my new magento website and I am in need to get all the products to this website. I do not need any other data! The problem is I only have the database of previous shop and no product csv file etc.

Can anyone suggest which parts I should move to a seperate .sql from that database dump to successfully inject previous shop's products to my new database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to install a clean magento instance over your old database, then export the products to csv an import them in the new shop.

I tried once moving only certain tables from one website to an other and that backfired instantly because of different attribute ids.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion, just tried it and only one error is messing the import
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`PigiDov56`.`catalog_product_entity`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`) ON ), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_type_id`, `type_id`, `sku`, `has_options`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, '2015-03-13 06:57:33', '2015-03-13 06:57:33')

Comment: should I create the previous stores attributes prior the import of .csv file?

Comment: did that and all products showing :) Thank you!